# linux terminal web browser

Tags: linux, browser, terminal, robots.txt

Is there a program I can run in terminal that will spit out a webpage's output? Basically I want to redirect its output (robots.txt) from a webpage to a txt file.

Answer (score 5):

[Wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) has this option, amongst others; this will output the page to standard output:

```
wget -O - http://www.example.com/robots.txt
```

and this will write into a file that you specified:

```
wget -O /whatever/output/file/you/put/here.txt http://www.example.com/robots.txt
```

If you want to append multiple commands to one file, you can use the shell's [redirection](http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/io-redirection.html) capabilities. This will append the content of the page to the end of the specified file, preserving its previous content:

```
wget -O - http://www.example.com/robots.txt >> /home/piskvor/yourfile.txt
```

Comment: But then, `wget http://www.example.com/robots.txt` will store in `./robots.txt` immediately.

Comment: @larsmans: True in this case, where the filename is obvious; but wget will happily create a file named `index.php?x=y&z=1` when asked for `http://example.net/index.php?x=y&z=1`; also, the current directory (`./`) can have unexpected values when invoked e.g. from a cron script or through `system()`. Though it is mostly a matter of personal preference, I like to specify the output file explicitly.

Comment: I thought of wget but I am iterating through a bunch of websites I have and it would be better for me to use the standard output and dump all the results to one file...can I do that with wget?

Comment: @Piskvor: I was commenting on a previous version of the answer, where only the `-O -` command was given. Gave you a +1, btw., and it's a good idea to teach the OP about `wget`'s `-O` option.

Comment: @keith: I don't think that `wget` can append to a file, but you can use it together with the shell's `>>` "append output to file" . Edited.

Comment: Isn't there a basic web browser for terminal?

Comment: @keith: There are text-mode browsers (e.g. `elinks`), if that's what you mean, but I'm not sure how scriptable they are; alternately, you could use a headless browser like [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which is built to be fully scriptable. Although controlling HTMLUnit is relatively simple, it is a slightly larger task than scripting a few wget calls.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet has been a well-known (though now forgotten, I guess) tool for looking at a web page. The general idea is to telnet to the http port, to type an http 1.1 GET command, and then to observe the results on the screen. A good explanation is [**http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279466**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279466)

A  [**Google search**](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=netgear+fvs318g+user+manual&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGHP_enUS431&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&pq=telnet%20to%20web%20page%20get&xhr=t&q=telnet+web+page+get&cp=7&pf=p&sclient=psy&rlz=1B3GGHP_enUS431&source=hp&aq=0j&aqi=&aql=&oq=telnet+web+page+get&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c47720ba43ce4197&bs=1) yields a whole bunch more.

**EDIT:** deleted extraneous, unrelated junk May 23 2011

Comment: Redirecting putty's output is decidedly non-trivial (not to mention that `putty.exe` is likely not a Linux command); also, how does ssh fit into this?

Comment: @Piskvor -- Huh? You must be thinking of something else. Putty is a terminal emulator whose output is redirected by a simple Linux '>' character, just as you'd redirect any other terminal output. Putty.exe is an emulator that runs on the PC. ssh is the preferred -- secure -- flavor of telnet that most ISPs use these days. Please reverse your downvote; it was completely unjustified.

Comment: 1) I'm aware what `ssh` is, and I'm aware what PuTTY is; 2) how do Internet Service Providers fit into this? Did you mean "hosting providers"? ISP is a company that gets your data from/to Internet, hosting providers house servers; 3) webpages are not served over SSH, they're served via HTTP(S); although secure pages use SSL, that's very much *not* the same thing. You may be thinking of remote shell (and you are correct that it used to be accessible via telnet, which was pretty much completely replaced by ssh). IMHO the answer is not directly relevant to the question, hence the downvote.

Comment: @Piskvor -- Fair enough. I'll edit my answer to explain more fully what I am getting at. I have to attend to things here at lat -71 first, though.

Comment: @Pete Wilson: I'm looking forward to that :)

Comment: @Piskvor -- of course I mean **longitude** -71. At lat -71, I'd be huddled in my yurt and snacking on dried hickory-'n'-honey-flavored llama chips.

Comment: Pete Wilson: hmm, yes, it might be slightly complicated to get an uplink there :D

Comment: @Piskvor -- when are you going to revert your ill-considered downvote, eh?

Comment: @Pete Wilson: I see no downvote of mine on your answer, having rescinded it after your first edit. Apparently I'm not the only user of SO who can vote.

Comment: @Piskvor -- oops! I apologize and thanks for your rescission. See you next time. It's been a pleasure.